# timer job programatically check status

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs

Is there a way to check for the status of a timer job, I need to know the last time it executed and its status, that it run correctly?

Comment: This issue has been answered previously. [see this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120672/check-if-a-sharepoint-timer-job-is-currently-running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SPWebApplication w = GetYourSPWebApplicationFromSomewhere();
foreach( var e in w.JobDefinitions["YourJobName"].HistoryEntries)
{
    var jobStatus = e.Status;
    var startTime = e.StartTime;
    // TODO: Do your stuff with Status and StartTime
}

var sc = SPFarm.Local.Services;
foreach (var e in sc["YourServiceName"].JobHistoryEntries)
{
    var jobStatus = e.Status;
    var startTime = e.StartTime;
    // TODO: Do your stuff with Status and StartTime
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Kjetil Gullen's and Paul Schaeflein solutions will work fine for completed tasks (succeeded or aborted for some reason), the entries for the **currently running** jobs are not yet present in the `JobHistoryEntries`.

You can include running jobs in your check by using the `RunningJobs` property of `SPService` (for all jobs running under a SharePoint service) or `SPWebApplication` (then the scope is limited to jobs running in web app).
Code example for the first case is in [StackOverflow's answer to "Check if a SharePoint timer job is currently running"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17063044/889779), and for the second case in [SharePoint: list running timer jobs (C#)](http://buli.waw.pl/sharepoint-list-running-timer-jobs-c/) article.

Answer (score 0):

[SPWebApplication.JobHistoryEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.jobhistoryentries.aspx)

[SPService.JobHistoryEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spservice.jobhistoryentries.aspx)

Comment: example of working code you have?