# How to identify the jobs which are running?

Tags: 2010, powershell, timer-jobs, script

I need to find the jobs which are running currently. This is to check the longest running jobs. Is there any powershell sript to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a script which will give you some

```
# Get current date
$date = Get-Date

# Show current date

Write-Host "Looking for running jobs with a Last Run Time of greater than or equal to" $date

# Get all Timer jobs and iterate

Get-SPTimerJob | ForEach-Object {

  # Get last run time for job

  $lastRunTime = $_.LastRunTime

  # If run time is greater than/equal to write it out

  if ($lastRunTime -ge $date)

{
 Write-Host $_.Name", last run at" $_.LastRunTime

}

}
```

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/5b6e8096-0783-4eaa-be7d-1951e6c3bf7e/powershell-get-running-timer-jobs

Alternatively Check these post:

[timer job programatically check status](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32968/timer-job-programatically-check-status)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748621.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to find the currently running jobs?

Comment: if you run the above code it will tell currently running jobs.more explanation about above steps....http://iedaddy.com/2011/09/sharepoint-2010using-powershell-to-display-currently-running-timer-jobs/

Answer (score 0):

The way to get actual running timer jobs was posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/48a69fbd-eb1d-45eb-aec4-5a007e114a23/get-running-timer-jobs-by-powershell?forum=sharepointdevelopment#1ed091bf-d374-4c9e-865d-5851fae261a7):

```
(Get-SPFarm).TimerService.RunningJobs
```